# CSV issues in SQL---need help

Tags: sql

I have this Split function which i got it from some site, now my problem is I am having one table where I want to push in imagespath. For now user can pass two images but in future there might be rise in the number of images required so we have used comma separated column which is a bad practice but was required in this case. Now when retrieve this images I want to segregate those images based on their ids

in database

```
1  abc.png,xyz.png
2  fgvm.png,ghy.jpg
```

like I want

```
Imagepath    ID
abc.png      1
xyz.png      1
fgvm.png     2
ghy.jpg      2
```

Using in the split function I'm doing this

```
 select * from dbo.split ((SELECT ImagePath
    FROM  dbo.AdvtManagement(nolock)),',')
```

But this query would give me like this

```
id val
1  abc.png
2  xyz.png   
3  fgvm.png
4  ghy.jpg
```

Can somebody help me with what I want?

split code

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
   returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
   as       
   begin       
       declare @idx int       
        declare @slice varchar(8000)       

        select @idx = 1       
            if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

       while @idx!= 0       
       begin       
           set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
           if @idx!=0       
               set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
           else       
              set @slice = @String       

           if(len(@slice)>0)  
               insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

           set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
           if len(@String) = 0 break       
       end   
   return       
   end
```

Comment: we'll need the code for the split() function that you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select A.ID, S.Items
from AdvtManagement as A
  cross apply
    dbo.split(A.ImagePath, ',') as S
```

Same code with some test data

```
with AdvtManagement(ID, ImagePath) as
(
  select 1, 'abc.png,xyz.png' union all 
  select 2, 'fgvm.png,ghy.jpg' 
)

select A.ID, S.Items
from AdvtManagement as A
  cross apply dbo.split(A.ImagePath, ',') as S
```

Result:

```
ID  Items
--  -------
1   abc.png
1   xyz.png
2   fgvm.png
2   ghy.jpg
```

Comment: @user - That is strange. S is not a column, it is an alias for the table returned by the split function. What does your statement look like?

Comment: @user - what version of SQL are you using?

Comment: @user - I agree with Mikael; can you show us the exact code you are using to get your error message?  Mikael's answer should work, perhaps there is a typo somewhere?

Comment: i got my answer the query should be this way

 SELECT P.ID,ST.val
FROM AdvtManagement AS P
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SPLIT(P.ImagePath,',') AS ST;

Thanks Mikael

Comment: it should be S.val or S.* not s.items